# QueueUserAPC fails with invalid handle?

Tags: windows, code-injection

I'm trying to figure out why QueueUserAPC fails, the error code is `6`, which is `ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE`

The DLL exists, the OpenThread works too,

Attached source code,

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    DWORD pid;
    vector<DWORD> tids;
    if (FindProcess(L"calc.exe", pid, tids)) {
        HANDLE hProcess = ::OpenProcess(PROCESS_VM_WRITE | PROCESS_VM_OPERATION, FALSE, pid);

        auto p = ::VirtualAllocEx(hProcess, nullptr, 1 << 12, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_READWRITE);
        wchar_t buffer[] = L"c:\\msgbox.dll";
        ::WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, p, buffer, sizeof(buffer), nullptr);

        for (const auto& tid : tids) {
            HANDLE hThread = ::OpenThread(THREAD_SET_CONTEXT, FALSE, tid);
            if (hThread != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
                ::QueueUserAPC((PAPCFUNC)::GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(L"kernel32"), "LoadLibraryW"), hThread, (ULONG_PTR)p);
                printf ("QueueUserAPC: %d\n", GetLastError());
            } else {
                printf ("OpenThread failed (%d): %d\n", tid, GetLastError());
            }
        }
        ::VirtualFreeEx(hProcess, p, 0, MEM_RELEASE | MEM_DECOMMIT);
    } else {
        puts ("process not found");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[`OpenThread`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684335(v=vs.85).aspx) -

> If the function fails, the return value is NULL.

so condition

```
if (hThread != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
```

is error. need

```
if (hThread != NULL)// or if (hThread)
```

I guess that in your case `hThread == 0`

also need understand that:

> When a user-mode APC is queued, the thread is not directed to call the
>   APC function unless it is in an alertable state.

really even if you use correct thread id/handle - your code will be no effect - *APC* not executed. insert *APC* have sense only if you know what thread is doing, that he wait for APC.

one is point, when `QueueUserAPC` worked - if you yourself call `CreateProcess` with `CREATE_SUSPENDED` and then call `QueueUserAPC` (in xp before call `QueueUserAPC` you must call `GetThreadContext` because xp at thread start insert also internal insert APC to it (to `LdrInitializeThunk`) - and if you just (without arbitrary wait or `GetThreadContext`(this is exactly wait) call `QueueUserAPC` - your APC can inserted *before* system APC - as result process begin executed not from `LdrInitializeThunk` but from your func and crashed. begin from vista this problem is gone and we can not use this hack) .

this will be worked because just before call exe entry point ntdll always call `ZwTestAlert` - this call check - are exist APC in thread queue and execute it. as result your APC will execute after all DLL in process got `DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH`, `TLS` initialized, etc.. but just before exe entry point begin executed. in context of first thread in process. for this case use `QueueUserAPC` the best injection way